# Запись которая попадает в диапазон дат mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста в записи таблицы mysql есть две даты 2019-06-10 и 2019-07-10.
`$date = "2019-06-15";`
Как составить условие если `$date` входит в диапазон дат между первой и второй тогда показываем эту дату?
Сейчас запрос такой:

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE (date_create BETWEEN '".$row_calendar_process['date_create']." 00:00:00' AND '".$row_calendar_process['run_up']." 23:59:59')
```

Comment: `... where DATE(date_field) >= '1111-11-11' and DATE(date_field) <= '2222-22-22'`, или этот AND можно заменить оператором between, как вам уже ответили пока писал коммент) `DATE()` это функция которая берёт только дату, даже если там формат/запись datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться оператором BETWEEN.

```
SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
```

Пример взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822648/how-do-i-query-between-two-dates-using-mysql).

**UPD**

Исходя из Ваших правок в вопросе, должно быть **приблизительно** как-то так:

```
"SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ($date BETWEEN '".$row_calendar_process['date_create']." 00:00:00' AND '".$row_calendar_process['run_up']." 23:59:59')"
```

Comment: Смотрите, у нас 3 даты. Нужно условие если $date входит в диапазон между двумя датами. $date это текущая дата.

Comment: `date_field` это же поле по которому делаем поиск.

Comment: Да. Вы же значение даты из поля таблицы берёте?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста составить запрос. Первая дата - `date_create` , вторая дата `run_up` , третья дата `$date`

Comment: Чтобы составить запрос нужно знать структуру таблиц. Да и что Вам это даст? Ведь принцип, который я привёл всё равно не изменится. Изменятся только даты в запросе.

Comment: Добавил запрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Там нужно поменять одно (см. UPD ответа).